# Images not showing when I add bootstrap classes

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I found a similar question here but I couldn't find a solution.

I'm using twitter-bootstrap 3.3.6 . When I add a bootstrap class to my div elements that contains images, the images are not displaying. But images are visible in code inspector in the browser.

```
<div class = "tab1 grow col-sm-12">
    <a href = "#/tab1" class = "tooltips">
        <img ng-src="{{ imageUrlProfile }}">
        <span>
            <strong>Profile</strong><br />
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Images are loading from angularJS.

Controller.js :

```
application.controller('app', function($rootScope, $scope) {
        $rootScope.imageUrlProfile = 'images/profile-icon.png';
        $rootScope.imageUrlWork = 'images/exp-icon.png';
        $rootScope.imageUrlEdu = 'images/edu-icon.png';
        $rootScope.imageUrlContact = 'images/phone-icon.png';

});
```

Relevant CSS styles are :

```
.tab1, .tab2, .tab3, .tab4, .tab5
{
    margin: 30px 30px 0px 30px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.tab1 img, .tab2 img, .tab3 img, .tab4 img, .tab5 img
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Why are you setting the urls on `$rootScope`?

Comment: @NexusDuck I want to change the image after clicking on it.

Comment: Why not just set them on $scope? This way they will be available everywhere, is that what you want?

Comment: I need to access the urls outside the controller. That's why i'm using $rootScope.